# UIImagePickerController not working

Tags: xcode, uinavigationcontroller, uiimageview, uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller

I am using xcode 4.5.2 and i want to use the `UIImagePickerController` on my navigationBar based app, everything works perfect unless the image keeps blank after the user picks the image.

the user should tab on a button->choose camera or existing from ActionSheet->Pick the image, and then .. nothing is showing !!

i've added the delegates `<UINavigationControllerDelegate,UIActionSheetDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate>` and linked everything in IB properly .. am very sure of that except am not sure about this method:

```
- (void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)thePicker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)imageInfo{

[[imgPicker parentViewController] dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

    UIImage *img = [imageInfo objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage"];
    currentImg.image = nil;
    self.currentImg.image = img;

}
```

i used this also:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)img editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editInfo {
image.image = img;
[[picker parentViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

and nothing happened ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLVED**

missed to add this line:

```
    self.imgPicker.delegate = self;
```

in viewDidLoad :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using `[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];` instead of using the edited image.  Usually you check to see if the edited image exists, use it if it does, and if not then use the original image.

Something like this:

```
- (void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *) picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *) info {
    NSString *mediaType = [info objectForKey: UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];
    UIImage *originalImage, *editedImage, *imageToSave;

    // Handle a still image capture
    if (CFStringCompare ((CFStringRef) mediaType, kUTTypeImage, 0) == kCFCompareEqualTo) {
        editedImage = (UIImage *) [info objectForKey:
                                   UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
        originalImage = (UIImage *) [info objectForKey:
                                     UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

        if (editedImage) {
            imageToSave = editedImage;
        } else {
            imageToSave = originalImage;
        }
    }

    self.currentImg.image = imageToSave;
}
```